# 2 String object have same address

Tags: java, string, java-8

This is as per Java8

```
    String s = "Hello1";
    String ab1 = new String(s) ;
    String ab2 = new String(s) ;
    System.out.println("s = " + s.hashCode());
    System.out.println("ab1 = " + ab1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("ab2 = " + ab2.hashCode());
```

output is coming as

```
s = -2137068097
ab1 = -2137068097
ab2 = -2137068097
```

s should be on String pool
ab1 and ab2  is on heap with different address as different object

but all 3 got same address

Comment: Hash code != heap address.

Comment: String overrides its hashcode method. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Hash code is not an "address".

Comment: If equal strings had different hash codes, the world would end. Or at least the part of the world that depends on hash tables working.

Comment: @user14387228 …and `switch` statements over strings.

Answer (score 2):

HashCode is not Heap Address/memory Location. 
Have a look at String hashCode implementation

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Hence for same length value & value whose ascii conversion and then addition returns same value gives same hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

The hashcode is not the actual memory address value. To prove this, we can use the == operator on the all three combination of variables. All three gives false as to confirm that the memory address are not the same for them.

```
System.out.println(s == ab1);
System.out.println(ab1 == ab2);
System.out.println(s == ab2);
```